# VideoCore use of Variables Issue

Tags: ios, swift, videocore

I'm trying to use variables with my VCSimpleSession. I currently have the width and height set up, and they are working fine, but I cannot get the framerate and bitrate ones to work.

Heres a look:

```
var session: VCSimpleSession!

var streamWidth:Int = Int(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("settingsWidth")!)!
var streamHeight:Int = Int(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("settingsHeight")!)!
var streamFramerate:Int = Int(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("settingsFramerate")!)!
var streamBitrate:Int = Int(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("settingsBitrate")!)!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    session = VCSimpleSession(videoSize: CGSize(width: streamWidth, height: streamHeight), frameRate: streamFramerate, bitrate: streamBitrate, useInterfaceOrientation: false)
    previewView.addSubview(session.previewView)
    session.previewView.frame = previewView.bounds
    session.delegate = self

}
```

I'm getting an error on frameRate and bitrate that is Cannot invoke initializer for type 'VCSimpleSession' with an argument list of type '(videoSize: CGSize, frameRate: Int, bitrate: Int, useInterfaceOrientation: Bool)'

I looked at the VCSimpleSession.h file and seen that frameRate and bitrate are both int values, so I'm confused why I'm getting this error. (Language is Swift by the way)

Here's a link to VideoCore on GitHub: https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close to solving my problem. The issue lies down to the frameRate and bitrate needs to be `Int32()` not `Int()`.

So this is what the final product should look like:

`session = VCSimpleSession(videoSize: CGSize(width: streamWidth,   height: streamHeight), frameRate: Int32(streamFramerate), bitrate: Int32(streamBitrate), useInterfaceOrientation: false)`

Comment: are you able to stream to your server from iOS device?

Comment: can you help me running the sample...I am getting the below issue

ClientState: 2
ClientState: 3
ClientState: 4
ClientState: 5
ClientState: 6
received server window size: 2500000
received peer bandwidth limit: 2500000 type: 2
Request to change incoming chunk size from 128 -> 4096
Received invoke
pktId: 1
received invoke _result
tracked command: connect
ClientState: 7
Received invoke
pktId: 0
received invoke onBWDone
ClientState: 11

Comment: Saty - can you create a new question on Stack Overflow, and paste the link here. Typically we keep different issues separate.

Comment: I have posted a new question. Would you please look into it?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058269/videocore-not-creating-rtmp-session